# How to remove skeleton from a model?

Tags: rigging

I have bought a 3d character on turbosquid. I opened it in Unity and everything loads fine except the animations. I then imported the skeleton to Mixamo to find out the skeleton is messed up. I use the set joints manually in Mixamo, but when it tries to fix the issue, the hands get attached to the butt/hips. I would like to get rid of the skeleton and remake it. How would I go about doing this?

I believe what I am trying to do would be called derigging? I could then use Mixamo's autorig tool to make a better skeleton.

Comment: Bring in a Cleric.

Comment: Are you a Cleric?

Comment: No, I'm merely a low-level Ranger.

Answer (score 1):

Select all bones - delete all bones.
Select all weight maps - delete all weight maps.
If anything else remains, is it related to rigging - delete it.